# Longest sequence in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, sublist

I have to remove the longest sequence of prime numbers from a list in Prolog.
I'm new in Prolog and I can't find a way to get to the longest sequence...
Here's what I've done until now:

```
divisible(X,Y):-
  0 is X mod Y.
divisible(X,Y):-
  X > Y + 1,
  divisible(X,Y+1).

is_prime(2).
is_prime(3).
is_prime(P):-
  integer(P),
  P>3,
  P mod 2 =\= 0,
  not(divisible(P,3)).
```

This one removes the prime numbers from the list..

```
removeP([],[]).
removeP([H],[H]):-
  not(is_prime(H)).
removeP([H|T],[H|L]):-
  not(is_prime(H)),
  removeP(T,L).
removeP([H|T],L):-
  is_prime(H),
  removeP(T,L).
```

And here I've tried to find the longest sequence, but I have no idea what to do next

```
longest([],[]).
longest([H],[H]):-
  is_prime(H).
longest([H],[]):-
  not(in_prime(H)).
longest([H|T],L):-
  ....
```

Comment: Please provide some sample queries together with the answers you expect.

Comment: I assume you are not interested in subsequences, but in sublists. cf https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence vs https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring .

Comment: For exemple, if I have the list [1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 7, 8], the resulted list will be [1, 3, 5, 4, 8] as [2,5,7] is the longest .

Comment: Ok. What if the list is `[1,3,5,4, 2,5,7, 8, 2,5,7, 9]`? Should both occurrences of `[2,5,7]` be removed?

Comment: What if the list is `[1,3,5,4, 2,5,7, 8, 2,3,5, 9]`? Should all longest sublists (comprising only of primes) be removed? Or should we rather get two answers (one with `[2,5,7]` removed, the other with `[2,3,5]` removed)?

Comment: I guess it should be removed all of them..if the size is the same.

Answer (score 0):

libraries, specially [aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate), help to harness nondeterminism:

```
remove_longest(Pred, L, R) :-
    aggregate(max(C,Xc/Yc), P^(append([Xc,P,Yc],L), maplist(Pred,P), length(P,C)), max(C,X/Y)),
    append(X, Y, R).
```

the predicate (is_prime for your case) is left generic. In this example run, I use just identity of atom 'a':

```
?- remove_longest(=(a), [1,2,3,a,a,4,5,a], R).
R = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, a].
```

Comment: Interesting, can this be made non-quadratic?